# git aws.push return error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently signed up for a free usage tier account on AWS and found its features very useful. It is actually my first time managing a web server so it is a challenge for me because I grew up being a developer only. I read the documentation and been brought up to the elastic beanstalk. I managed to create my first PHP application.

But, when I try pushing commits to my web app, an http request failed error 400 always appearing. I even follow the user interactions on this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=332711&#332711 but also failed.

I even created a new user restricted only for beanstalk management, copied its access and secret key to the aws.config.

It appears that all my credentials are correct because i didn't see any "authentication failed" errors so I think it is mainly on the request part.

error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting authentication failures because your clock far enough out of sync with the server to cause the signature you compute to not be valid. The minutes seem correct, but the hours are off (15 hours in the future) which could possibly point to a time zone issue.

Please verify that the time and time zone on the system you are pushing from is correct.

Hope this helps.